# Regex does not identify '#' for removing "#' from words starting with "#'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, data-science

How to remove `#` from words in a string if it is the first character in a word. It should remain if it is present by itself, in the middle of a word, or at the end of a word.

Currently I am using the regex expression:

```
test = "# #DataScience"
test = re.sub(r'\b#\w\w*\b', '', test)
```

for removing the `#` from the words starting with `#` but it does not work at all. It returns the string as it is

Can anyone please tell me why the `#` is not being recognized and removed?

Examples -

```
test - "# #DataScience"
Expected Output - "# DataScience"

Test - "kjndjk#jnjkd"
Expected Output - "kjndjk#jnjkd"

Test - "# #DataScience #KJSBDKJ kjndjk#jnjkd #jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#""
Expected Output -"# DataScience KJSBDKJ kjndjk#jnjkd jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#"
```

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Can you at least format it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = '# #DataScience'
b = 'kjndjk#jnjkd'
c = "# #DataScience #KJSBDKJ kjndjk#jnjkd #jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#"
regex = '(\s+)#(\S)'

import re
print re.sub(regex, '\\1\\2', a)
print re.sub(regex, '\\1\\2', b)
print re.sub(regex, '\\1\\2', c)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string by space `' '` to make a list of all words in the string. Then loop in that list, check each word for your given condition and replace hash if necessary. After that you can join the list by space `' '` to create a string and return it.

```
def remove_hash(str):
    words = str.split(' ')  # Split the string into a list
    without_hash = []  # Create a list for saving the words after removing hash
    for word in words:
        if re.match('^#[a-zA-Z]+', word) is not None:  # check if the word starts with hash('#') and contains some characters after it.
            without_hash.append(word[1:])  # it true remove the hash and append it your the ther list
        else:
            without_hash.append(word)  # otherwise append the word as is in new list
    return ' '.join(without_hash)  # join the new list(without hash) by space and return it.
```

Output:

```
>>> remove_hash('# #DataScience')
'# DataScience'
>>> remove_hash('kjndjk#jnjkd')
'kjndjk#jnjkd'
>>> remove_hash("# #DataScience #KJSBDKJ kjndjk#jnjkd #jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#")
'# DataScience KJSBDKJ kjndjk#jnjkd jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#'
```

Your make your code shorter(but a bit harder to understand) by avoiding if else like this:

```
def remove_hash(str):
words = str.split(' ' )
    without_hash = []
    for word in words:
        without_hash.append(re.sub(r'^#+(.+)', r'\1', word))
    return ' '.join(without_hash)
```

This will get you the same results

Comment: That was a really smart way to the do it! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Do give the following pattern a try. It looks for a sequence of '#'s and whitespaces that's located at the beginning of the string and substitute it for '# '

```
import re

test = "# #DataScience"
test = re.sub(r'(^[#\s]+)', '# ', test)

>>>test
# DataScience
```

You can play with the pattern further here: https://regex101.com/r/6hfw4t/1

Comment: I see! This helps me out a lot! Thank you!